# LinkML schemata for DOI registration?

Tags: schema, doi, linkml

At https://www.crossref.org/xml-samples/ there are some examples for XML and Json Files that if i understand right are needed to register DOIs for certain items.

I'd love to know whether there is already a LinkML schema equivalent available for these so that conversion between different formats would be supported

Comment: Not a direct answer but the kbase developers have a schema that interoperates with crossref, they may be aware of other efforts, see https://github.com/kbase/credit_engine/blob/develop/schema/kbase/linkml/credit_metadata.yaml